# Large Integer Literal Source Formatting in C++

Tags: c++, integer, code-formatting

I'm working with very large integer literal defines eg:

```
#define X 999999999999
```

To improve readability I tried changing this to:

```
#define X 999/**/999/**/999/**/999
```

But the compiler was like "nah bru.."

Is there any way to make these more readable?

Just to clarify, this question is asking only about the appearance of the values in the source code. I'm not asking how to format these values in a printf or anything.

Comment: It depends on context in which this literal will be used

Comment: Short answer: Sorry, but no. If memory serves, Ada allows you to embed underscores into integer literals, like `x = 123_456_789;`, but C and C++ (alas) do not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in a define (but not outside of a define):

```
#define X 999##111##333##444
```

I'm not sure that I'd recommend it, but it's legal. (`##` is the preprocessor token concatenation operator.)

You explicitly didn't ask about output formatting, so you're probably not interested in input formatting either, but both of them can be made locale-aware, which includes allowing locale-specific grouping characters.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any reason you wouldn't recommend it?

Comment: @fauxCoder, just my sense of aesthetics. It's portable, standards-compliant, and zero-overhead, so there's no non-aesthetic argument against it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>
BOOST_PP_SEQ_CAT((345)(678)(901))
```

Which would show up in source code as:

```
345678901
```